# Error protractor and selenium : StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: selenium, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a issue in my test e2e. I was reading a lot of protractor and selenium and don't find a solution.

My test e2e is :

```
    it('Recorro tabla de MCSS, verificando que existan datos', function () {
        browser.sleep(1000);
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        logger.info("Recorro tabla de MCSS, verificando que existan datos");

        utils.awaitElement(element.all(by.repeater('item in alertsMCSS'))).then(function (rows) {
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                row.all(by.tagName('td')).then(function (columns) {
                    utils.awaitElement(columns[0].getAttribute('innerText')).then(function (instancia) {
                        logger.info('MCSS: ' + instancia);
                        expect(instancia !== "");
                    });
                    utils.awaitElement(columns[1].getAttribute('innerText')).then(function (valor) {
                        logger.info('Valor: ' + valor);
                        expect(valor !== "");
                    });

                });
            });
        });
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });
```

The function utils.awaits (I found this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543599/what-this-error-mean-stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-pa) ) but I don't know if really works or not:

```
var awaitElement = function (item) {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var ee = item;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ee), 5000);
    expect(ee.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    return ee;
};
```

When I run the test, sometimes it's all okey, and sometimes the test fails. The description of failure is :

```
    StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document 
 at WebDriverError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
        at StaleElementReferenceError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:227:5)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    From: Task: WebElement.getAttribute(innerText)
```

**What's the issue ? How can I resolved?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)

Comment: There's too much code provided, makes it hard to follow.  Please limit it to the problematic spec and the associated code.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to approach this problem with some of the built in Protractor functionality. My guess is that you are referencing elements that exist but has been lost by reference.

#### Code Snippet

Below is my attempt to refactor the code above with some of the built in Protractor APIs.

```
it('Recorro tabla de MCSS, verificando que existan datos', function () {
  browser.sleep(1000);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  logger.info("Recorro tabla de MCSS, verificando que existan datos");

  // element all by repeater should only be used for AngularJS and not Angular
  // see element.all each methods link below.
  element.all(by.repeater('item in alertsMCSS')).each(function(rowElement) {

    // after we get each row, we could get all table data for that row
    columnElements = row.all(by.tagName('td');

    // use the element.all get method to get the first and second elements
    instanciaElement = columnElements.get(0);
    valorElement = columnElement.get(1);

    // instead of using innerHtml, think about using getText
    instanciaElement.getText().then(function(text) {
      logger.info('MCSS: ' + text);

      // use jasmine not tobe method. see link below.
      // expect(text !== "") is not a valid jasmine statement
      expect(text).not.toBe("");
    });
    valorElement.getText().then(function(text) {
      logger.info('Valor: ' + text);
      expect(text).not.toBe("");
    });
  });

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

#### Using Protractor APIs

Instead of doing a `forEach`, think about using the [element.all each](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each)  method. After you cycle through each row, you can get a handle for all table data elements. Then you can use [element.all get](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) to a specific element by index. After we have the element we want to log and test, we could use the built in [getText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) method. Since this returns a promise, we need to resolve the promise to get the text. From there we should consider using a valid jasmine statement. See expectations jasmine docs [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Expectations).